# Last-modified header with Template annotations in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to modify response headers while keep using Template annotations? Particularly interested in last-modified header. I know I can do `$this->render` and get a response object but I really like the idea of annotations and would like to keep using them as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall that there's a Pull Request in progress to facilitate this kind of behaviour, but unfortunately I can't find it.

If you don't mind doing it yourself, you can use the same approach that's used by the [@Cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html) annotation and create a listener to set the appropriate headers once the response has been generated (see [here](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/CacheListener.php)), but this decoupling can make it difficult to generate an accurate (i.e. tied to entities) last-modified date.